# Arrange columns based on the order of values in an array - and buttons disappearing

Tags: vba, excel, button

I have this code which is looking in a column (On a different sheet at XFD1) and creating an array from the values in that column.  Then it is searching for those values one at a time across a row on the current sheet.  When it finds a match, it cuts the column and inserts it at the location that corresponds to the order of the values in the array.

I'm not getting any compile errors.  I placed a button (not ActiveX) on the worksheet and used it to execute the code.  Here is what I see:

1. Nothing appears to happen.  Columns are not moved at all.
2. The computer is obviously "thinking " because the whirly-gig is spinning away.
3. And here is the Mysterious part -  The button disappears!  it never comes back.  I placed several buttons on the worksheet and tried them all.  The button disappears every time.

I really need to get this working.  All I want is to reorder the columns to the same order as my list on the other sheet (95 items in the list).  I thought this code would do it but I seem to have entered the Twilight Zone and things are not as they seem (at least from my perspective)!

Here it is:

```
Sub Reorder_Columns()
    Dim arrColumnOrder(1 To 95) As String
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim Found As range
    Dim tick As Integer

        For index = 1 To 95
            arrColumnOrder(index) = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("XFD1")
        Next index

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    tick = 1
        For index = LBound(arrColumnOrder) To UBound(arrColumnOrder)
           Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColumnOrder(index), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
           SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
               If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                   If Found.column <> tick Then
                   Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                   Columns(tick).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                   Application.CutCopyMode = False
                   End If
               tick = tick + 1
               End If
        Next index

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How can you expect to reorder anything when you put 95 instances of the same value into your array?

Comment: And the button might have "moved" due to column insertions.

Comment: Your button disappears because the option "Cut, Copy and Paste inserted objects with their parent cells" is not checked.  *Options >> Advanced >> Cut, Copy and Paste*

Comment: @Jeeped I don't appreciate your sarcastic tone at all.  "How could you expect to reorder anything..."  almost sounds like ridicule.  First, I made a few simple mistakes when I wrote the code.  Second, I could not see my mistakes.  That is WHY I asked the question.  This place is supposed to be a place where people help each other.  If I had all the answers, I would never need to come here looking for help from more experienced people.  No response would have been much better than the comment you made.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question concerning what was wrong with my original code is:

First, I was trying to set the size of the array but should have been working with a dynamic array as I expect the data in my array column will grow as I add more columns to the sheet I am trying to sort.  So, `Dim arrColumnOrder(1 To 95) As String` should have been `Dim arrColumnOrder As Variant`.

I was then trying to iterate over my array with

```
    For index = 1 To 95
        arrColumnOrder(index) = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("XFD1")
    Next index
```

Which of course is all wrong.  I replaced this with

```
arrColumnOrder = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("XFD1:XFD95").Value
```

Then, in

```
       Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColumnOrder(index), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

Should have been "... `Find (arrColumnOrder(index, 1)`..."

The answer to why the button was moving is that I did not Set the format option of the button (right click the button, Format Control>Properties>Select "Don't move or size with cells.")  So when things were moving (and weirdly because my code was all wrong)  The button moved with the cell when the column was copied and pasted.

Here is my final code and it works and does exactly what it is expected to do.  Namely, it creates an array from the data in the range "XFD1:XFD95" (on a separate worksheet where I have the column headers stored in the proper order), then it sorts the columns in the active worksheet to match the order of the array.  I did not want to explicitly call a sheet name as this will run on varying sheets.  Using Find as opposed to Match, works just fine for me as this is not a huge amount of data I'm dealing with so speed is not an issue.

```
Sub Reorder_Columns()
    Dim arrColumnOrder As Variant
    Dim index As Interger
    Dim Found As range
    Dim tick As Integer

    arrColumnOrder = UserFormDropDownDataSheet.range("XFD1:XFD95").Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    tick = 1
        For index = LBound(arrColumnOrder) To UBound(arrColumnOrder)
           Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColumnOrder(index, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
           SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
               If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                   If Found.column <> tick Then
                   Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                   Columns(tick).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                   Application.CutCopyMode = False
                   End If
               tick = tick + 1
               End If
        Next index
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For me, one of the big lessons here is to not try to write code when I have only slept for two hours!  I was really tired and making silly mistakes because I was not thinking clearly.  I got a good night's rest and then this morning I was easily able to see where I went wrong.